# Is God referring to a literal fire in Deuteronomy 32:22?

Tags: deuteronomy

Deuteronomy 32:22 NASB

> “For a fire is kindled in My anger, And burns to the lowest part of Sheol, And consumes the earth with its yield, And sets on fire the foundations of the mountains.”
> ‭‭

Is God referring to a literal of fire or is it just a way of describing His wrath?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the disciples at Luke 24:32 saying, "Were our hearts not burning within us". Of course, this is a more positive connotation.

Answer (score 2):

> "For a fire is kindled in mine anger, and shall burn unto the lowest hell, and shall consume the earth with her increase, and set on fire the foundations of the mountains." - Deuteronomy 32:22 KJV

The fire could be literal. It could be metaphoric. Neither case is necessary. Either case is possible.

The same consideration also applies to related passages that refer to God as a fire: Deut 4:24, Deut 9:3, and Heb 12:29.

> "For the Lord thy God is a consuming fire, even a jealous God." - Deut 4:24 KJV

> "Understand therefore this day, that the Lord thy God is he which goeth over before thee; as a consuming fire he shall destroy them, and he shall bring them down before thy face: so shalt thou drive them out, and destroy them quickly, as the Lord hath said unto thee." - Deut 9:3 KJV

> "For our God is a consuming fire." - Heb 12:29 KJV

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"God is spirit" (John 4:24).  Thus, a literal fire needs literal material to burn which a spirit is not.

The whole passage of Deut 32:19-22 is poetic hyperbole about the fierce anger of God.  Note the following couplet (V20):

> He said: “I will hide My face from them;
>
> I will see what will be their end.

At face value this is a contradiction to turn away to see what would happen.  Then there is the repeated references to God's anger:

- V19: proviked to anger
- V20: perverse
- V21a: provoked my jealousy
- V21b: enraged me
- V22: a fire has been kindled by my anger, etc

The "fire of circumstances" is outlined in the following verse which enumerate the various disasters that this will involve

- V23: heap disasters on them
- V24a: wasted from hunger
- V24b: ravaged by pestilence and bitter plague
- V24c: wild beasts
- V24d: venom of vipers
- V25: the sword (ie war) will take their children

... and so forth.  The whole passage is quintessential Hebrew poetry about the anger of God and how it is implemented.  This same combination of consequences is regularly seen in the way God deals with wayward Israel using "sword, famine and plague and wild beasts:

- 1 Chron 21:12 - between three years of **famine**, three months of being swept away before your enemies and overtaken by their **swords**, or three days of the sword of the LORD—days of **plague** upon the land, with the angel of the LORD ravaging every part of Israel.’ Now then, decide how I should reply to Him who sent me.”
- 2 Chron 20:9 - ‘If disaster comes upon us—whether **sword** or judgment, **plague** or **famine**—we will stand before this temple and before You, for Your Name is in this temple. We will cry out to You in our distress, and You will hear us and save us.’
- Jer 21:9 - Whoever stays in this city will die by **sword and famine and plague**, but whoever goes out and surrenders to the Chaldeans who besiege you will live; he will retain his life like a spoil of war.
- Jer 24:10 - And I will send against them **sword and famine and plague**, until they have perished from the land that I gave to them and their fathers.’ ”
- Jer 27:13 - Why should you and your people die by **sword and famine and plague**, as the LORD has decreed against any nation that does not serve the king of Babylon?
- Jer 29:18 - I will pursue them with **sword and famine and plague**. I will make them a horror to all the kingdoms of the earth—a curse, a desolation, and an object of scorn and reproach among all the nations to which I banish them.
- Jer 42:22 - Now therefore, know for sure that by **sword and famine and plague** you will die in the place where you desire to go to reside.”
- Eze 5:12 - A third of your people will die by **plague** or be consumed by **famine** within you, a third will fall by the sword outside your walls, and a third I will scatter to every wind and unleash a **sword** behind them.
- Eze 5:17 - I will send **famine and wild beasts** against you, and they will leave you childless. **Plague** and bloodshed will sweep through you, and I will bring a **sword** against you. I, the LORD, have spoken.”
- Eze 7:15 - The **sword** is outside; **plague** and **famine** are within. Those in the country will die by the sword, and those in the city will be devoured by **famine and plague**.
- Eze 12:16 - But I will spare a few of them from **sword and famine and plague**, so that in the nations to which they go, they can recount all their abominations. Then they will know that I am the LORD.”

I also note that the same four judgments are those of the first four seals in Rev 6 which are taken from the same four judgments as listed in Lev 26:14-28, specifically:

- plague (V14-17)
- famine (V18-20)
- wild animals (V21-22)
- sword/war (V23-26)

Lev 26 is part of the blessings and curses of the Israelite covenant.  These are essentially repeated in Deut 28:1-14 for blessings; and, Deut 28:15-68 for curses; and then summarized in Deut 32 in the Song of Moses.

Answer (score 0):

Deuteronomy 32:22 is a small section of a poem called "The Song of Moses". The whole song is from Deu 32:1-43. This is a sad song as it is a prophesy of Moses to the fate of the God's people what they would become. Deu  31:29 read;

> 29 For I (Moses) know that after my death you (Israelite) are sure to become utterly corrupt and to turn from the way I have commanded you. In days to come, disaster will fall on you because you will do evil in the sight of the Lord and arouse his anger by what your hands have made.”

The prophesy realized several hundreds year later, and we know that the Israelite was destroyed by Assyria, Babylonia, but not by fire. So yes, in Deu 32:22, it is a literal fire a description of the great wrath of God.